# Is there a way to draw a ring through Pixi.js?

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

I'd like to draw a circle with an empty center like a ring using Pixi.js.

I tried it with a mask and a filter, but I couldn't.

Is there a way to draw it like the picture I posted.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

try this one it might help you

```
var graphics = new PIXI.Graphics()
graphics.lineStyle(/*border width*/10,/*border color*/ 0xFFBD01, 1);
graphics.drawCircle(200, 200, 50);
graphics.endFill();
```